# How to access image files outside project folder in html?

Tags: html

I put the user uploaded image files on separate disk partition on my local dev server(OS windows) which is outside of project folder. I need to access those image files in html pages of web app.

I tried out giving paths like: `http://localhost:8080/C://tmp/thumbnails/pl_2001.JPEG` but no help. Image is not fetched. How to properly access such files in html pages ?

Comment: what language(s) are you using.

Comment: i use java server side but that doesn't matter, no..?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use rewrites for this so you don't display sensitive folder names.

if you are using php you can use .htaccess rewrites for a slug something like `images/someimage.mime` and split/get what's after `images/` and have a php function that takes the filename and makes sure it exists and if you want you can check if its a valid mime then send a header to say its a `image/somemime` so the browser can display the image instead of gibberish it will display without it.

```
$filename = "C://tmp/" . $file;
if(file_exists($filename)){
    $img = getimagesize($filename);
    if(in_array($img['mime'], array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','etc'))){
        header("Content-type: image/" . $img['mime']);
        readfile($filename);
    }else{
        //default image
    }
}else{
    //default image
}
```

I haven't tested this but it should give you a idea on getting you started. If this isn't the language you are looking for try searching for something similar for your language you are using.